# how to concat 1row 2 field as 2 row 1 field in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

example 

+---------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| idTurnament|        name                      | TeamA | TeamB |
+---------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
|                13 |        A VS B       |           5    |        6   |
+---------------+--------------------+---------+----------+

as

+---------------+--------------------+---------+
| idTurnament|        name                      | Team  |
+---------------+--------------------+---------+
|                13 |        A VS B       |           5    |
|                13 |        A VS B       |           6    |
+---------------+--------------------+---------+

Comment: i'm using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`:

```
select idTurnament, name, TeamA as team
from yourtable
union all
select idTurnament, name, TeamB as team
from yourtable
```